# calling a init method of component b from a

Tags: coldfusion

In one of my components, `abc.cfc`, I am extending another one: `xyz.cfc`. Component `xyz.cfc` has an init() method which is expecting: datasource,username,password.

In my application, I am using it like this:

```
<cfset this.mappings = structNew() />
<cfset this.mappings["/com"] = getDirectoryFromPath(getCurrentTemplatePath()) & "com/">
<cfset Application.tools = new com.abc()>
```

Now in abc.cfc I am doing the following:

```
<cfcomponent hint="The File which acces the Information about the Detail" extends="xyz">
```

and xyz.cfc has the following function:

```
<cffunction name="init" access="public" output="No" returntype="mysql" hint="Initializes the component">
        <cfargument name="datasource" required="Yes" type="string" />
        <cfargument name="username" required="Yes" type="string" />
        <cfargument name="password" required="Yes" type="string" />

        <cfscript>
            variables.instance = structNew();
            setDatasource(argumentcollection=arguments); // set datasource information
            clearCache(); // create cache struct

            variables.instance.trim = true;

            return this;
        </cfscript>
    </cffunction>
```

It is producing an error like this:

```
 The DATASOURCE parameter to the INIT function is required but was not passed in.   The error occurred in C:/ColdFusion11/cfusion/wwwroot/project1/admin/Application.cfc: line 28
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just pass the argument values in the constructor call:

```
<cfset Application.tools = new com.abc(datasource=datasource, etc)>
```